# Program stalls during long runs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fortran, openmp

I am running a simulation on a computer running Ubuntu server 10.04.3. Short runs (<24 hours) run fine, but long runs eventually stall. By stall, I mean that the program no longer gets any CPU time, but it still holds all information in memory. In order to run these simulations, I SSH and nohup the program and pipe any output to a file.

Miscellaneous information:

The system is definitely not running out of RAM. The program does not need to read or write to the hard drive until completion; the computation is done completely in memory. The program is not killed, as it still has a PID after it stalls. I am using openmp, but have increased the max number of processes and the max time is unlimited. I am finding the largest eigenvalues of a matrix using the ARPACK fortran library.

Any thoughts on what is causing this behavior or how to resume my currently stalled program?

Comment: How do you know it's not running out of RAM?

Comment: The system has 98G of RAM and with the parameters I am using, the program conservatively uses ~3G (calculated and observed).

Comment: Is the process a 32-bit or 64-bit process?

Comment: @birryree The machine is 64 bit (x86_64). I do not know whether my fortran program is automatically 64 bit. I am using gfortran as my compiler.

Comment: @user779810 - if you built it on that machine, gfortran will default to 64-bit. You can make sure by using the `file` command to find out if your binary is built as a 32-bit or 64-bit build: `file your_executable_name`.

Comment: You might want to write your solution in an actual answer below and mark it accepted - this makes sure your question won't show up in the list of unanswered questions

Answer (score 4):

I assume this is an OpenMP program from your tags, though you never actually state this.  Is ARPACK threadsafe?

It sounds like you are hitting a deadlock (more common in MPI programs than OpenMP, but it's definitely possible).  The first thing to do is to compile with debugging flags on, then the next time you find this problem, attach with a debugger and find out what the various threads are doing.   For gdb, for instance, some instructions for switching between threads are shown [here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/gdbthreads.html).

Comment: ARPACK determines eigenvalues by analysing the results of matrix vector multiplications. The only parallel portion of my code is during the multiplication and ARPACK subroutines are called outside of parallel portions. When the run time is under ~24 hours (smaller matrices), the program works fine and the results are repeatable.

Comment: Ok, good, that eliminates one possibility.   So I'd suggest doing the attach-gdb thing on the next stall, and/or see if a one-thread-only large job stalls.

Answer (score 2):

Next time your program "stalls", attach GDB to it and do `thread apply all where`.

- If all your threads are blocked waiting for some mutex, you have a
  deadlock.
- If they are waiting for something else (e.g. read), then you need to figure out what prevents the operation from completing.

Generally on UNIX you don't need to rebuild with debug flags on to get a meaningful stack trace. You wouldn't get file/line numbers, but they may not be necessary to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way of understanding what a running program (that is, a process) is doing is to attach a debugger to it with `gdb program *pid*` (which works well only when the program has been compiled with debugging enabled with `-g`), or to use strace on it, using `strace -p *pid*`. the `strace` command is an utility (technically, a specialized debugger built above the `ptrace` system call interface) which shows you all the system calls done by a program or a process.

There is also a variant, called `ltrace` that intercepts the call to functions in dynamic libraries.

To get a feeling of it, try for instance `strace ls`

Of course, `strace` won't help you much if the running program is not doing any system calls.

Comment: This is indicative of the kind of output I get. (I haven't figured out the formatting yet)   `futex(0x2b97714, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0  
futex(0x6780ae0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0  
brk(0x2bbb000)                          = 0x2bbb000  
brk(0x49ae000)                          = 0x49ae000  
brk(0x67a1000)                          = 0x67a1000  
futex(0x2b986a4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 23  
futex(0x2b986a4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 `